# When two pages is next to each other, how many times of random IO will happen?

Tags: database

In 6.830 lec6, it said after converted a unclustered index into a clustered index for a range query, the times of random I/O will be decreased from per record to per page. So here implies that if two pages is next to each other, there will be 2 random I/O to be done.

But it still says one of the characteristics of heap file is `Sequentially stored pages, no seeks between records or pages` , so here implies only 1 random I/O will happen.

[image: Range query using unclustered Index, with per record random I/O]

[image: Range query using clustered Index, with per record random I/O]

[image: Heap File feature]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clustered index` guarantees the arrangement between indexes and the tuples, but does not guarantee the arrangement between 2 nearby indexes.

In condition that `Insert` operation results in a page split, the new generated page will not be next to the old page, but the indexes of them maybe still next to each other. So in clustered indexes, when searching point moves from one page to another, there may happen random I/O.